# Microsoft SQL Count Rows in 15 minute Intervals

Tags: count, group

Here's how I do it in Oracle - But I cannot get anything I try to be equivalent in Microsoft SQL:
select count(*) as "Count"
/* (Seconds to Day) + (Whole 15 minute periods in day)/(One 15 minute Period)/(15 minute periods in a day) {in seconds, and 'SSSSS' is Seconds past mindnight} */
,to_char(trunc(stbl.ROW_TS)  -- column is row timestamp.
+ FLOOR(to_number(to_char(stbl.ROW_TS,'SSSSS'))/900)/96, -- (15*60))/((24*60*60)/(15*60))
'YYYY-MM-DD  HH24:MI:SS') as "Time_BRKT"
from dba.SOME_TABLE stbl
where stbl.ROW_TS between to_timestamp('08/15/2023 12:00:00',MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
and     to_timestamp('08/16/2023 12:00:00',MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
group by to_char(trunc(stbl.ROW_TS)
+ FLOOR(to_number(to_char(stbl.ROW_TS,'SSSSS'))/900)/96, -- (15*60))/((24*60*60)/(15*60))
'YYYY-MM-DD  HH24:MI:SS')
order by to_char(trunc(stbl.ROW_TS)
+ FLOOR(to_number(to_char(stbl.ROW_TS,'SSSSS'))/900)/96, -- (15*60))/((24*60*60)/(15*60))
'YYYY-MM-DD  HH24:MI:SS') asc;
Hoping for an example of a direct conversion of this to something that works in Microsoft SQL.

Expecting a list of counts and start of 15 minute periods.